# Can we ever have Documents with different fields in a single Lucene index?

Tags: java, lucene

This question has cropped up in my mind because, when constructing the output from a query's results, I want to make sure that I extract all the `Fields` (and not try extracting non-existent ones) from the `Documents` in the `TopDocs`... in anticipation of finding indices which contain `Documents` from an older version of my app.

The interesting/curious thing is that you have a method `Document.getFields()`.  I.e. the `Document` class, rather than, for example, `IndexSearcher` or `DirectoryReader`, is responsible for telling us the `Fields` used.  Theoretically, therefore, you could store and later retrieve `Documents` with a different set of `Fields`.

At this stage of my TDD I am just going to test that fields are extracted from the first `Document` in the `TopDocs`, and assume that all the others have the same fields.

But are there any use cases where one might have `Documents` with differing fields?